# How many groups of seven can be chosen to work on the project?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A computer programming team has $13$ members. Suppose two team members insist on working together or not at all. How many different groups of seven can be chosen to work on the project?

I cannot understand the solution for the question.

$${11 \choose 5 } + {11 \choose 7}$$

Comment: Hint:  there are two types of teams.  Type $A$ has both, type $B$ has neither.  Count the two types separately.

Comment: Answer: $\binom{11}{7}$ after you've fired the two primadonnas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Al* and *Bob* want to work together. Then, the number of possible groups with both *Al* and *Bob* is the number of groups of $5$ out of $11$, that is
$$\binom{11}5$$
The number of possible groups without *Al* and *Bob* is the number of groups of $7$ out of $11$, that is
$$\binom{11}7$$
The total number of possible groups is then
$$\binom{11}5+ \binom{11}7$$